# what is the use of Flash Lite, is this same as Flash Action Script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashlite

I want to know is Flash Lite is same as Flash Action Script programing.
When/where we use Flash Lite?

Comment: For example on Sony Ericsson phones you can use a Flash Lite animation as a wallpaper/background/menu. A background that responds to acceleration is cool. :) For example check out this page: http://se-stuff.net/flash-wallpapers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the Wikipedia [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) page.

The Adobe [Intro to Flash Lite 2](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flashlite2_as_intro.pdf) (PDF), describes which features are supported partially and which are introduced specifically for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Flashlite is the flavor of Flash for embedded devices, since full Flash is not typically supported on devices with limited resources.  Flashlite only supports as2, and MOST, but not all, of the actionscript classes are the same.  For example, the MovieClip object doesn't have the getRect() function, but it does have getBounds().  SharedObject is another piece that doesn't work the same.

One thing to note is that Adobe announced support for flash player 10 in mobile devices, which support more of the modern flash features, like actionscript 3 and flex.  So maybe in the future, you'll use flash 10 on your embedded device, but for now, we're stuck with flashlite.